# groovy: postgres driver error: unnest:org.postgresql.jdbc.PgSQLXML@fb0c5b3

Tags: postgresql, groovy

A groovy script which executes beloved sql query outputs an error. 
However, same query works fine in pgAdmin4.

Postgres driver version: postgresql-42.2.2.jre7.jar

```
println con.firstRow("SELECT unnest(xpath('/html/body/span/text()'::text, body::xml)) FROM (SELECT REPLACE((SELECT body FROM email_service.message ORDER BY expiry DESC LIMIT 1), '<!DOCTYPE html>', '') AS body) pin")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide the stacktrace

Comment: Do you mean Command Prompt output?

Comment: the the full error with stacktrace. the `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgSQLXML@fb0c5b3` is the xml object returned from server. it's not an error

Comment: I got just this: [unnest:org.postgresql.jdbc.PgSQLXML@26b9569e] . I don't know how to get stacktrace. I just tarted pick groovy up. Is there a groovy command which gives stacktrace?

Comment: For this query: println con.firstRow("SELECT REPLACE ((SELECT body FROM email_service.message ORDER BY expiry DESC LIMIT 1), '<!DOCTYPE html>', '')") works fine. So I guess it doesn't like unnest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[unnest:org.postgresql.jdbc.PgSQLXML@26b9569e]` - is not an error

it's an [xml-object](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgSQLXML.html) that you have to download from server.

you can try

```
println con.firstRow("SELECT unnest(...) as COL1 FROM ...").COL1.getString()
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I applied your suggestion and it's working.